Does Ayurveda has better curative powers than the Modern Medicine?
How does Ayurveda's approach to healing compare to modern medicine in terms of efficacy and holistic wellness? Can Ayurveda's emphasis on personalized treatments and natural remedies offer superior curative powers compared to the standardized approach of modern medicine?

This question can only be answered through scientific speculation and is very much opinion based alone. I also doubt any supporting evidence from Shastra can be given.
